# Mysql Prepared Statement using same parameter multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote stored procedure like this:

```
  DELIMITER $$
   CREATE PROCEDURE searchByTerm(term VARCHAR(300))
    BEGIN
    SET @statment = "Select name,description from products where name like '%?%' OR description like '%?%'";
    PREPARE stmt FROM @statment;
    SET @a = term;
    SET @b = term;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @a,@b;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
  END$$
```

calling it as :

```
CALL searchByTerm('xyz');
```

it results in following error:

```
Error Code : 1210
Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE
```

Am i doing anythng wrong? I know it can be done with concat statement but why it's not working like this? Can't i use same parameter multiple times? Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)** in your query

```
SET @statment = "Select name,description 
                 from products 
                 where name like CONCAT('%', ? ,'%') OR 
                       description like CONCAT('%', ? ,'%')";
```

so your full query will look like this,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE searchByTerm(term VARCHAR(300))
  BEGIN
    SET @statment = "Select name,description 
                     from products 
                     where name like CONCAT('%', ? ,'%') OR 
                           description like CONCAT('%', ? ,'%')";
    PREPARE stmt FROM @statment;
    SET @a = term;
    SET @b = term;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @a,@b;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
  END$$
```

Comment: great... it worked..many thanks :) it was really a silly mistake that i didn't consider '?' as part of string